# ADO Command in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ado, vba

I'm using Access 2010 with Excel 2010 and I'd like to perform a query using ADO Command. See below what I did in Excel VBA:

```
Public Sub test()
On Error GoTo TrataErro

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Query As String

Set cnn = DBcnn
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Query = "SELECT * FROM tblTermos WHERE Termo like @Termo"

cmd.CommandText = Query

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, "%[%")

Set rst = cmd.Execute

Do Until rst.EOF
    MsgBox rst.Fields("Termo").Value & " " & rst.Fields("id_Grupo").Value
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

DBdisconnect cnn, rst, cmd

Exit Sub

TrataErro:

TrataErro "Erro durante a execução do procedimento ""TrataTermo""."

End Sub
```

No value is returned using this query above, but in my DB I have lines with "[", "word1[", "[word2" and others. However, when a rewrite the specific line as below, I get only the line with "[" value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, "[")
```

How could I perform this query **using ADO Command** and returning all values that contain "[" inside the string?

If I didn't explain very well my situation, please, ask me more information about. I'm new in this community.

Comment: You indicate you have values in the `Termo` column that start with a `[`. What happens when you add your parameter with a value of `"[%"`?  Like this: `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, "[%")`

Comment: Hello FreeMan. When I add a parameter with "[%" value (as you wrote above), no value is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... returning all values that contain "[" inside the string

The `[` character has special meaning in a `Like` pattern.  It is used to match  a range of characters.  For example, this pattern would match *a*, *b* or *c* anywhere within *Termo*.

```sql
Termo Like '%[a-c]%'
```

When you want to match the `[` character itself, put it in a range by itself.

```sql
Termo Like '%[[]%'
```

In your code, append the parameter like this ...

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Termo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, "%[[]%")
```

Comment: ADO is regex-like? Who knew?

Comment: No, it's not that much like regex.  :-)  At least I've never found a way to make a backslash force a literal character in a `Like` pattern.

Comment: Hello HansUp, I'll try to use the code like you show above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a fixed parameter you're looking for, you could eliminate the parameter by doing this:

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM tblTermos WHERE Termo like %[%"
```

If you have different things you're selecting for you could do something like this:

```
Dim MyParm as string
MyParm = "%[%"
Query = "SELECT * FROM tblTermos WHERE Termo like '" & MyParm & "'"
```

Doesn't solve your exact issue, but they are possible work arounds.

Comment: Hello. As you did, you aren't using ADO Command / Parameter, right?

Comment: Correct. you would skip the `cmd.Parameters.Append ...` line, but leave the rest of it. Sorry for not specifying. Check out HansUp's response though, that may fix it.